# HtmlSanitizer + ASP.NET Core 2 with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, html-sanitizing

When I use [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) without DI it works well.

HtmlSanitizer without DI:

[image: HtmlSanitizer without DI]

But when I want to get `HtmlSanitizer` using DI.

1. I added to Startup.cs file:

   ```
   services.AddSingleton<IHtmlSanitizer, HtmlSanitizer>();
   ```
2. I used constructor of repository to get instance of `IHtmlSanitizer` but
   in the injected `HtmlSanitizer` instance, `AllowedTags`, and `AllowAttributes` are empty.

HtmlSanitizer with DI:

[image: HtmlSanitizer with DI]

How can I get `HtmlSanitizer` with filled properties using DI?

Comment: Take a look at the "Framework Types" section of [this blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/). It gives the general advise for @Nkosi's answer.

Comment: @Steven, are optional parameters in a single constructor follow to the same anti pattern, as multiple constructors? If yes, it will be good to mention  them in your old post.

Comment: According to https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/issues/431#issuecomment-1422688465, the issue was fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .Net framework dependency injection is trying to inject the optional constructor parameters

```
    public HtmlSanitizer(IEnumerable<string> allowedTags = null, IEnumerable<string> allowedSchemes = null,
        IEnumerable<string> allowedAttributes = null, IEnumerable<string> uriAttributes = null, IEnumerable<string> allowedCssProperties = null, IEnumerable<string> allowedCssClasses = null)
    {
        AllowedTags = new HashSet<string>(allowedTags ?? DefaultAllowedTags, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        AllowedSchemes = new HashSet<string>(allowedSchemes ?? DefaultAllowedSchemes, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        AllowedAttributes = new HashSet<string>(allowedAttributes ?? DefaultAllowedAttributes, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        UriAttributes = new HashSet<string>(uriAttributes ?? DefaultUriAttributes, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        AllowedCssProperties = new HashSet<string>(allowedCssProperties ?? DefaultAllowedCssProperties, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        AllowedAtRules = new HashSet<CssRuleType>(DefaultAllowedAtRules);
        AllowedCssClasses = allowedCssClasses != null ? new HashSet<string>(allowedCssClasses) : null;
    }
```

[Source](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/blob/master/src/HtmlSanitizer/HtmlSanitizer.cs#L62)

which results in empty collections being used by the DI container to initialize the  target `HtmlSanitizer` class.

In this case, use the factory delegate when registering the class and call the constructor (just as was done when not using DI)

```
services.AddSingleton<IHtmlSanitizer>(_ => new HtmlSanitizer());
```

Or simply create the instance and register it with the DI container

```
IHtmlSanitizer sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
services.AddSingleton<IHtmlSanitizer>(sanitizer);
```